# iOS: Remote push notification showing key for button title instead of value

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm implementing the usage of remote push notifications that uses a key to look up the Localizable.strings file, but the problem is that when I send a notification the alert dialog pops up with the key as the button title label instead of it's value.

So if I do the following for the main body of the push notification:

```
"body"=> "Test notification",
"action-loc-key"=>"ActionButtonInstall"
```

The app should look up the Localizable.strings file for the ActionButtonInstall key, which is "Install", but instead the alert dialog shows "ActionButtonInstall" as the button. I know that if the value for the key is null it will use a default OK button, but in this case it's not null, it just seems to fail to look it up, so I'm quite stuck with this.

Essentially, under what conditions would the notification button show up with the key instead of the value?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you setting this? I use `MoonAPNS` in my app (`C#`) and set this on the server: `NotificationPayload(deviceToken, message, badge)`.

Comment: Typically it's coming from our server, but just for testing I'm using a ruby script that creates the notification and pushes it.

Comment: Based on what you describe, your server side code is correct. The problem must be with the `Localizable.strings` file of your app. Perhaps it's not in the correct location, or it's not deployed with the app for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Are your `body` and `alert-loc-key` keys in the body of an `alert` dictionary? It needs to be in the json format like so for the system to use it correctly:

```
"aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "alert-loc-key" : "ActionButtonInstall",
            "body" : "Test notification"
        },
    },
```

Comment: In future if you're unsure whether your answer is relevant to the OP you should usually try to comment and ask clarifying questions first. But in this case the question is 2 years old, so it's unclear if the OP still has this problem or will even return. So in this case posting an answer that might be helpful was probably the right call.